# Set-MsolUserPassword, ForceChangePasswordOnly-Parameter not documented

Tags: powershell, office365

I want to reset a bunch of user passwords, forcing them to choose a new one on their next login.

But what is the difference between Set-MsolUserPassword Parameter "ForceChangePassword" and "ForceChangePasswordOnly"?

Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoluserpassword?view=azureadps-1.0) is incomplete and most sites in the web use both parameters like this: `Set-MsolUserPassword -ForceChangePasswordOnly $true -ForceChangePassword $true`, but also without a detailed explanation of both params.

Comment: It's odd that the parameter is not explained. I've raised an issue for it on Github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/issues/150

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-ForceChangePassword $true requires user to change password at next login.
-ForceChangePasswordOnly $true prevents the command Set-MsolUserPassword from generating a random password if no password (-newpassword "123456") is on the command line.

Set-MsolUserPassword -userprinciplename xyzuser@xyz.com -ForceChangePassword $true 
Would generate a random password for the user ans set the flag that they must change the password. 
Set-MsolUserPassword -userprinciplename xyzuser@xyz.com -ForceChangePasswordOnly $true -ForceChangePassword $true

Would not generate a password and just cause user to be prompted to change the password.